# I have a pod networking failure when creating a mono-node cluster from scratch on a VM

Tags: networking, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have a problem with pods reaching the cluster DNS.

I am able to reach the cluster DNS from the host, but not from the pods.

I'm mainly doing this to learn how components within a cluster interact with each other.

What I missing?

Appreciate the help.

```
cluster CIDR: 10.200.0.0/24
kube-dns cluster IP: 10.96.0.10
service cluster IP range: 10.96.0.0/24

$ ip route
default via 10.26.8.1 dev ens33 onlink
10.26.8.0/21 dev ens33  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.26.8.173
10.200.0.0/24 dev cnio0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.200.0.1
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.0.1 linkdown

$ ip addr list
...
12: cnio0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 9a:7c:99:d0:34:05 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.200.0.1/24 brd 10.200.0.255 scope global cnio0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::987c:99ff:fed0:3405/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
...

# from the pod
$ kubectl exec -ti busybox3 -- ip route get 10.96.0.10
10.96.0.10 via 10.200.0.1 dev eth0  src 10.200.0.35

$ kubectl exec -ti busybox3 -- ip route get 10.200.0.32
10.200.0.32 dev eth0  src 10.200.0.35

## Unable to ping pod
$ kubectl exec -ti busybox3 -- ping 10.200.0.32
PING 10.200.0.32 (10.200.0.32): 56 data bytes
^C
--- 10.200.0.32 ping statistics ---
26 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
command terminated with exit code 1

$ kubectl exec -ti busybox3 -- nslookup kubernetes
Server:    10.96.0.10
Address 1: 10.96.0.10

nslookup: can't resolve 'kubernetes'
command terminated with exit code 1

# from the host
$ nslookup kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local 10.96.0.10
Server:         10.96.0.10
Address:        10.96.0.10#53

Name:   kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.32.0.1

## using the pod IP directly
$ nslookup kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local 10.200.0.32
Server:         10.200.0.32
Address:        10.200.0.32#53

Name:   kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.32.0.1

$ kubectl    get pods -n kube-system -owide
NAME                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP            NODE       NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
coredns-68567cdb47-8bqbc   1/1     Running   0          16m   10.200.0.32   myhostname   <none>           <none>
coredns-68567cdb47-j7w5v   1/1     Running   0          16m   10.200.0.33   myhostname   <none>           <none>

$ cat /var/lib/kubelet/kubelet-config.yaml
kind: KubeletConfiguration
apiVersion: kubelet.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
authentication:
  anonymous:
    enabled: false
  webhook:
    enabled: true
  x509:
    clientCAFile: "/var/lib/kubernetes/ca.pem"
authorization:
  mode: Webhook
clusterDomain: "cluster.local"
clusterDNS:
  - "10.96.0.10"
podCIDR: "10.200.0.0/24"
resolvConf: "/etc/resolv.conf"
runtimeRequestTimeout: "15m"
tlsCertFile: "/var/lib/kubelet/myhostname.pem"
tlsPrivateKeyFile: "/var/lib/kubelet/myhostname-key.pem"

$ sudo iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Tue Dec 17 22:25:50 2019
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [75825:12120908]
:INPUT ACCEPT [73784:12027210]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [2041:93698]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [72541:12755845]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [72541:12755845]
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Dec 17 22:25:50 2019
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Tue Dec 17 22:25:50 2019
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [2265:357288]
:FORWARD DROP [70:3150]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [2254:381251]
:KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES - [0:0]
:KUBE-FIREWALL - [0:0]
:KUBE-FORWARD - [0:0]
:KUBE-SERVICES - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j KUBE-FIREWALL
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m comment --comment "kubernetes service portals" -j KUBE-SERVICES
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m comment --comment "kubernetes externally-visible service portals" -j KUBE-EXTERNAL-SERVICES
-A FORWARD -m comment --comment "kubernetes forwarding rules" -j KUBE-FORWARD
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m comment --comment "kubernetes service portals" -j KUBE-SERVICES
-A OUTPUT -j KUBE-FIREWALL
-A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -m comment --comment "kubernetes service portals" -j KUBE-SERVICES
-A KUBE-FIREWALL -m comment --comment "kubernetes firewall for dropping marked packets" -m mark --mark 0x8000/0x8000 -j DROP
-A KUBE-FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A KUBE-FORWARD -m comment --comment "kubernetes forwarding rules" -m mark --mark 0x4000/0x4000 -j ACCEPT
-A KUBE-FORWARD -s 10.200.0.0/24 -m comment --comment "kubernetes forwarding conntrack pod source rule" -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A KUBE-FORWARD -d 10.200.0.0/24 -m comment --comment "kubernetes forwarding conntrack pod destination rule" -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Dec 17 22:25:50 2019
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Tue Dec 17 22:25:50 2019
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [71:3399]
:INPUT ACCEPT [1:249]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [10:600]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [10:600]
:CNI-08323572f8c1b7437b5b2d5a - [0:0]
:CNI-6ffb7cac9d9ed164b2d5ba7b - [0:0]
:CNI-75946e699f4851c447169397 - [0:0]
:CNI-7fc98eb6f610acba6ece3337 - [0:0]
:CNI-a96f59ef769e0d335cecc5fa - [0:0]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:KUBE-MARK-DROP - [0:0]
:KUBE-MARK-MASQ - [0:0]
:KUBE-NODEPORTS - [0:0]
:KUBE-POSTROUTING - [0:0]
:KUBE-SEP-BAY6F2PYGJH5DEUE - [0:0]
:KUBE-SEP-G6EBKTWNJTOIEXU4 - [0:0]
:KUBE-SEP-GOBYNHXNZIF5W3D2 - [0:0]
:KUBE-SEP-HT77WNMWLBPE7QGR - [0:0]
:KUBE-SEP-LFB6X7K6BJJCW3R6 - [0:0]
:KUBE-SEP-LHZJOTZD4BS6MHNZ - [0:0]
:KUBE-SEP-VCPA7KUZVLOW57EQ - [0:0]
:KUBE-SERVICES - [0:0]
:KUBE-SVC-ERIFXISQEP7F7OF4 - [0:0]
:KUBE-SVC-JD5MR3NA4I4DYORP - [0:0]
:KUBE-SVC-NPX46M4PTMTKRN6Y - [0:0]
:KUBE-SVC-TCOU7JCQXEZGVUNU - [0:0]
:REDSOCKS - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -m comment --comment "kubernetes service portals" -j KUBE-SERVICES
-A OUTPUT -m comment --comment "kubernetes service portals" -j KUBE-SERVICES
-A POSTROUTING -m comment --comment "kubernetes postrouting rules" -j KUBE-POSTROUTING
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.200.0.32/32 -m comment --comment "name: \"bridge\" id: \"6cb90718739f0752baa8722dbfff1f9f03d0237962dc8985f8fb13d23d80b31d\"" -j CNI-a96f59ef769e0d335cecc5fa
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.200.0.33/32 -m comment --comment "name: \"bridge\" id: \"b0546397dbc9bf07b7c5b02a4dcc91d0a052e715c1d451c47d774211bcf5c1a4\"" -j CNI-6ffb7cac9d9ed164b2d5ba7b
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.200.0.34/32 -m comment --comment "name: \"bridge\" id: \"75b63b258fdd87fcd35e703e4a4bb39c9f11e2e5fd01a574d8a006e5e472234a\"" -j CNI-75946e699f4851c447169397
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.200.0.35/32 -m comment --comment "name: \"bridge\" id: \"e6244383918a970b53438d4e4198540c60778640c9c2a167ff77f39d7fd79bbb\"" -j CNI-7fc98eb6f610acba6ece3337
-A CNI-6ffb7cac9d9ed164b2d5ba7b -d 10.200.0.0/24 -m comment --comment "name: \"bridge\" id: \"b0546397dbc9bf07b7c5b02a4dcc91d0a052e715c1d451c47d774211bcf5c1a4\"" -j ACCEPT
-A CNI-6ffb7cac9d9ed164b2d5ba7b ! -d 224.0.0.0/4 -m comment --comment "name: \"bridge\" id: \"b0546397dbc9bf07b7c5b02a4dcc91d0a052e715c1d451c47d774211bcf5c1a4\"" -j MASQUERADE
-A CNI-75946e699f4851c447169397 -d 10.200.0.0/24 -m comment --comment "name: \"bridge\" id: \"75b63b258fdd87fcd35e703e4a4bb39c9f11e2e5fd01a574d8a006e5e472234a\"" -j ACCEPT
-A CNI-75946e699f4851c447169397 ! -d 224.0.0.0/4 -m comment --comment "name: \"bridge\" id: \"75b63b258fdd87fcd35e703e4a4bb39c9f11e2e5fd01a574d8a006e5e472234a\"" -j MASQUERADE
-A CNI-7fc98eb6f610acba6ece3337 -d 10.200.0.0/24 -m comment --comment "name: \"bridge\" id: \"e6244383918a970b53438d4e4198540c60778640c9c2a167ff77f39d7fd79bbb\"" -j ACCEPT
-A CNI-7fc98eb6f610acba6ece3337 ! -d 224.0.0.0/4 -m comment --comment "name: \"bridge\" id: \"e6244383918a970b53438d4e4198540c60778640c9c2a167ff77f39d7fd79bbb\"" -j MASQUERADE
-A CNI-a96f59ef769e0d335cecc5fa -d 10.200.0.0/24 -m comment --comment "name: \"bridge\" id: \"6cb90718739f0752baa8722dbfff1f9f03d0237962dc8985f8fb13d23d80b31d\"" -j ACCEPT
-A CNI-a96f59ef769e0d335cecc5fa ! -d 224.0.0.0/4 -m comment --comment "name: \"bridge\" id: \"6cb90718739f0752baa8722dbfff1f9f03d0237962dc8985f8fb13d23d80b31d\"" -j MASQUERADE
-A KUBE-MARK-DROP -j MARK --set-xmark 0x8000/0x8000
-A KUBE-MARK-MASQ -j MARK --set-xmark 0x4000/0x4000
-A KUBE-POSTROUTING -m comment --comment "kubernetes service traffic requiring SNAT" -m mark --mark 0x4000/0x4000 -j MASQUERADE
-A KUBE-SEP-BAY6F2PYGJH5DEUE -s 10.26.8.173/32 -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-BAY6F2PYGJH5DEUE -p tcp -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 10.26.8.173:6443
-A KUBE-SEP-G6EBKTWNJTOIEXU4 -s 10.200.0.33/32 -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-G6EBKTWNJTOIEXU4 -p udp -m udp -j DNAT --to-destination 10.200.0.33:53
-A KUBE-SEP-GOBYNHXNZIF5W3D2 -s 10.200.0.33/32 -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-GOBYNHXNZIF5W3D2 -p tcp -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 10.200.0.33:53
-A KUBE-SEP-HT77WNMWLBPE7QGR -s 10.200.0.32/32 -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-HT77WNMWLBPE7QGR -p tcp -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 10.200.0.32:53
-A KUBE-SEP-LFB6X7K6BJJCW3R6 -s 10.200.0.32/32 -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-LFB6X7K6BJJCW3R6 -p udp -m udp -j DNAT --to-destination 10.200.0.32:53
-A KUBE-SEP-LHZJOTZD4BS6MHNZ -s 10.200.0.33/32 -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-LHZJOTZD4BS6MHNZ -p tcp -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 10.200.0.33:9153
-A KUBE-SEP-VCPA7KUZVLOW57EQ -s 10.200.0.32/32 -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SEP-VCPA7KUZVLOW57EQ -p tcp -m tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 10.200.0.32:9153
-A KUBE-SERVICES ! -s 10.200.0.0/24 -d 10.96.0.10/32 -p udp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns cluster IP" -m udp --dport 53 -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.96.0.10/32 -p udp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns cluster IP" -m udp --dport 53 -j KUBE-SVC-TCOU7JCQXEZGVUNU
-A KUBE-SERVICES ! -s 10.200.0.0/24 -d 10.96.0.10/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 53 -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.96.0.10/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:dns-tcp cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 53 -j KUBE-SVC-ERIFXISQEP7F7OF4
-A KUBE-SERVICES ! -s 10.200.0.0/24 -d 10.96.0.10/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:metrics cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 9153 -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.96.0.10/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "kube-system/kube-dns:metrics cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 9153 -j KUBE-SVC-JD5MR3NA4I4DYORP
-A KUBE-SERVICES ! -s 10.200.0.0/24 -d 10.32.0.1/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/kubernetes:https cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 443 -j KUBE-MARK-MASQ
-A KUBE-SERVICES -d 10.32.0.1/32 -p tcp -m comment --comment "default/kubernetes:https cluster IP" -m tcp --dport 443 -j KUBE-SVC-NPX46M4PTMTKRN6Y
-A KUBE-SERVICES -m comment --comment "kubernetes service nodeports; NOTE: this must be the last rule in this chain" -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j KUBE-NODEPORTS
-A KUBE-SVC-ERIFXISQEP7F7OF4 -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.50000000000 -j KUBE-SEP-HT77WNMWLBPE7QGR
-A KUBE-SVC-ERIFXISQEP7F7OF4 -j KUBE-SEP-GOBYNHXNZIF5W3D2
-A KUBE-SVC-JD5MR3NA4I4DYORP -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.50000000000 -j KUBE-SEP-VCPA7KUZVLOW57EQ
-A KUBE-SVC-JD5MR3NA4I4DYORP -j KUBE-SEP-LHZJOTZD4BS6MHNZ
-A KUBE-SVC-NPX46M4PTMTKRN6Y -j KUBE-SEP-BAY6F2PYGJH5DEUE
-A KUBE-SVC-TCOU7JCQXEZGVUNU -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.50000000000 -j KUBE-SEP-LFB6X7K6BJJCW3R6
-A KUBE-SVC-TCOU7JCQXEZGVUNU -j KUBE-SEP-G6EBKTWNJTOIEXU4
COMMIT
# Completed on Tue Dec 17 22:25:50 2019

$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.0", GitCommit:"2bd9643cee5b3b3a5ecbd3af49d09018f0773c77", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-09-18T14:36:53Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.0", GitCommit:"2bd9643cee5b3b3a5ecbd3af49d09018f0773c77", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-09-18T14:27:17Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.9", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Comment: How have you created a cluster?  Have you been using any particular resource for that ?

Comment: @Nick I created the cluster from scratch (configuring the components one by one) - I'm sure I missed a bit during the kubelet/cni config.. maybe?

Comment: There is a tool called minikube if you would like to have cluster for tests. And there is a good tutorial called "Kubernetes the hard way" (however, it is not mono-node setup).

Comment: I'm trying to recreate the issue now. Hope to find an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, i have used minikube a lot, set up clusters with kubeadm as well (quite straightforward). I'm doing this to learn more about the internals of each kubernetes component. With this issue, I'm not sure what to troubleshoot next. Maybe by setting up a veth bridge, linking it to two different network namespaces and see if I can ping each namespace from one another? Like, what steps would you take / tools would you use to debug this further? Probably something on that VM that makes this fail.

Comment: And btw, I used Kelsey's kubernetes the hardest way guide to deploy a mono-node cluster on my VM

Comment: could you add the output of  `journalctl -b -u kubelet -l --no-pager | grep -i hairp` command?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204608/discussion-between-nick-and-aayoubi).